# Is Statefull doFn supported by google dataflow runner?

Tags: go, google-cloud-dataflow, beam

I cannot make a batch fn work on Dataflow. I used the one in example here in Go: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#state-timers-examples

The dofn receive element and trigger the OnTimer once and then everything get stuck (I can see it with logs).

I'am in streaming mode. So my first question is do Dataflow support Timers in Go? If yes what I'm doing wrong? I literrally copied the example.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for everyone struggling with same issue on Dataflow, you have to add this line is the OnTimer() callback:

```golang
fn.OutputState.ClearTag(tp, timer.Tag) // Clean up the fired timer tag. (Temporary workaround for a runner bug.)
```

(this line is present in the example on github but not in the documentation)

Comment: That's correct. It's a bug in Dataflow at present that I was hoping would be fixed by now. Sorry for the inconvenience. Ideally we wouldn't run into runner specific bugs like that.

Note that if you aren't using tags, the basic Clear can be used instead. It's the same thing as clearing with the provided (empty) tag.

The goal is to have support for state and timers in the default local runner by Beam 2.52 (if not by 2.51), to make these them clearer to learn and easier to document. We're well aware the Go Doc can be improved...